# couchapp: query with a key?

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

Could someone point me to an example of a Couchapp application that queries a view with a key based on user input from an HTML form?

I can't seem to either figure out how to do this or find an example on my own via google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

If you're using evently, then in `/evently/[whatever]/_changes`, instead of a fixed `query.json`, you can replace it with a `query.js` where you can dynamically return a query, e.g.:

```
function() {
  var key = /* ... */
  // get your key from the appropriate source (jquery, current page's URL, etc) 
  return {
    "view" : "recent-items",
    "key" : key,
    "limit" : 50
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you remember how to trigger the query again after changing the key?

Comment: Solved: $(this).trigger("_changes")